# std::string s = (std::string)"a" + "b" + "c"; OK?

Tags: c++

It works, no crashes. Is it OK?

edit: the reason I ask is that `std::string s = "a" + "b" + "c";` produces a compiler error, and `(std::string)"a"` just tells the compiler, "Just presume what "a" is pointing at is an std::string".  And I didn't actually know how std::string is implemented.

Thanks for the feedback from everyone.

Comment: I think you mean std::string s = (std::string) ("a" + "b" + "c"); ?

Comment: @BlackBear that wouldn't even compile, because you can not add pointers to each other.

Comment: @BlackBear: That will fail. His code casts "a" to a string object, and then does concatenation. Yours attempts to add two pointers, which will fail.

Comment: @sharth @Timbo: You mean arrays. :) (Which decay to pointers, then fail, yes.)

Comment: @BlackBear: No, because that wouldn't compile.

Comment: @BlackBear: No! `("a" + "b" + "c")` is not valid (it would just add three pointer values together).  The questioner wants to make the first value a `std::string` so that the + operator will do the desired thing.

Comment: @shart @Timbo @kristopher: ups, you're right. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  `+` is left-associative, so it's equivalent to `((std::string)"a" + "b")  + "c"`.  `std::string::operator+` is overloaded to take a `const char *` as the argument.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. That's fine.

It's mostly equivalent to doing

```
std::string s = "a";
s += "b";
s += "c";
```

Comment: Actually your interpretation is more effective than the topic author's one: you've got only one string object and he creates three `const string`s

Comment: @ssmir: He may or may not create three `std::string`'s, certainly not any that are `const`. They may be elided by the compiler, and move semantics certainly eliminate the three.

Answer (score 2):

> `(std::string)"a"` just tells the compiler, "Just presume what `"a"` is pointing at is an `std::string`"

No, this isn't what a cast to an object type means at all. A cast to an object type is an explicit request of a conversion. `(std::string)"a"` means "construct a temporary `std::string` from the literal (`const char[]`) `"a"`.

In the declaration `std::string s = (std::string)"a" + "b" + "c";`, this temporary lives until the initialization of `s` completes. (12.2 [class.temporary] / 4)

There are (at least) two further temporaries constructed, the result of applying `operator+` to the first temporary and `"b"` and the result of applying `operator+` to that temporary and `"c2"` This last temporary is used to copy-initialize `s`. Once the initialization is complete all of the temporaries are destroyed in the reverse order of their construction.

The initialization is valid and has well defined behaviour.

Comment: Hey, I appreciate that. So its not like primitive types then - I thought it would be the same. (int)"hello" or (char *)n, would act as I described.

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` has a member function `operator +` which takes a right-hand argument of type `const char *`. There is also a globally defined `operator +`s which allows for `const char *` to be on the left-side of the operator.

```
// std::string::operator + (const char *)
std::string a;
a = "b";

// global operator + (std::string, const char *)
std::string a;
a = (std::string)"b" + "c";

// global operator + (const char *, std::string)
std::string a;
a = "b" + (std::string)"c";
```

The reason the an argument must be type-cast to `std::string` because string literals are of type `const char *`. The problem with doing `"a" + "b"` is that the complier has no objects of type `std::string` in the assignment statement, and therefore attempts to add pointers together. To avoid this, you must have a term of type `std::string` of the left or right side of the `char *` term.

Answer (score 1):

Would be better:

```
std::string s(std::string("a") + "b" + "c");
```

Comment: I don't see why that's any better.

Comment: @GMan, it's more C++-like. :)

Comment: Maybe. I think your no-C-style-cast point was list amid the loss of copy-initialization as well, which was much easier to read.

Comment: If you're going to improve it, why not improve it all the way? `std::string s("abc");`